# How to place an item always over other items in PyQtGraph?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'd like to know if it's possible to place an item over other items, even when the item was added earlier than other items.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import QtCore, QtGui

class CandlestickItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, data):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.data = data  
        self.generatePicture()
    
    def generatePicture(self):
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        w = (self.data[1][0] - self.data[0][0]) / 3.
        for (t, open, close, min, max) in self.data:
            p.drawLine(QtCore.QPointF(t, min), QtCore.QPointF(t, max))
            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(t-w, open, w*2, close-open))
        p.end()
    
    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)
    
    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())

data = [  ## fields are (time, open, close, min, max).
    (1., 10, 13, 5, 15),
    (2., 13, 17, 9, 20),
    (3., 17, 14, 11, 23),
    (4., 14, 15, 5, 19),
    (5., 15, 9, 8, 22),
    (6., 9, 15, 8, 16),
]


plt = pg.plot()


sctItem = pg.ScatterPlotItem(symbol='s', pen=pg.mkPen(None), size=13, brush=(14, 40, 57, 255))
sctItem.setData( [1,2,3],[12,15,16] )
plt.addItem(sctItem)

candleItem = CandlestickItem(data)
plt.addItem(candleItem)



plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: customGraphicsItem')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

In the code above, sctItem is added earlier than candleItem and cannot be seen. Is there a way to keep an item over other items, whether of not new items are added after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`zValue`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#zValue) value decides the stacking order of the siblings (neighbors), so in this case if you want sctItem to be on top of its other siblings then just set it to 1 since by default it is 0.

```py
sctItem.setZValue(1)
```

Comment: That's what I need! Thank you!